# VirtualBox Python SDK, closeMachineSession -> XPCOM component has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, virtualbox

I am trying to run a VirtualBox machine using the python sdk.

I ran the following commands (based on the [documentation](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/SDKRef.pdf) page 32):

```
from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager
manager = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)
vbox = manager.vbox
name = "myVM"
mach = vbox.findMachine(name)
session = manager.mgr.getSessionObject(vbox)
progress = mach.launchVMProcess(session, "gui", "")

progress.waitForCompletion(-1) #successfully fires up myVM w/ GUI

manager.closeMachineSession(session) #error, see below
```

The error I get is:

> raise AttributeError, "XPCOM component '%s' has no attribute '%s'" % (self._object_name_, attr)
>   AttributeError: XPCOM component '@virtualbox.org/Session;1' has no attribute 'close'

I am trying to shutdown and close the VM from python.

Question:
How can I resolve this error and shut down the VM using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session.console.powerDown()` did the trick (I had to rtfm). I am still interested in knowing what the intention of that line is from the docs.

Comment: Just a guess, the XPCOM docs are out of date.  Would have to actually dig through the source but I imagine at one point `manager.closeMachineSession(session)` translated into a call to `session.close()` but that method has been eliminated or no longer shard over XPCOM.